# How to tell PendingIntent whether to create new or update existing broadcast

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

Imagine I am making a calendar. So people can schedule appointments, and people can update appointments. People can also cancel appointments.

I want to send people notification 15 minutes before their appointments. So I have the following method

```
public void scheduleNotification( Notification notification, long futureTimeInMillis, int id){
        Context context =MyApplication.getContext();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,NotificationPublisher.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID,id);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION,notification);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,futureTimeInMillis,pendingIntent);
    }
```

My problem is with `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)`

- if a user has updated an existing appointment, I want the new notification to replace the old notification for that appointment
- if a user creates a new appointment, I do not want the new notification to replace any existing notification.

So how do I tell PendingIntent whether to replace or create something new? Clearly `NotificationPublisher` is going to be the exact same class for all.

Comment: Just add two different methods for different button clicks such as update and create new

Comment: The point of the question is **how does the PendingIntent know whether I am adding a new notification or updating an existing one**

Comment: Create an intent with a different ID sometimes

Comment: I'm notification intent

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0 ,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

can be used to differentiate different `PendingIntent`s. You should use a differnt value for each unique alarm.